Function refuses to deserialize DateTimeOffset
My .NET 6 Azure Function is being sent a JSON payload including two DateTimeOffsets. I am pretty sure 6 in-process uses Newtonsoft for serialization.
{
    ...
    "CreatedDate": "2024-11-04T21:00:00.0000000+00:00",
    "DueDate": "2024-11-05T21:00:00.0000000Z".
    ...
}

In my Startup.cs I have even configured a JsonConverter<DateTimeOffset> though I think I shouldn't have to.
builder.Services.Configure<JsonSerializerSettings>(options =>
{
    options.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    options.Converters.Add(new DateTimeOffsetFormatConverter());
});

If I omit the two DateTimeOffset values then I don't get errors so it is definitely them causing the error.
I have also double-checked that the json is not malformed.
Locally everything works but deployed in Azure I keep getting:
Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.DateTimeOffset'.

Any suggestions as to what might be going on?
EDIT
The class being deserialized to is:
public class Data
{
    ...
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DueDate { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class DateTimeOffsetFormatConverter : JsonConverter<DateTimeOffset>
{
    private const string ReadDateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK";
    private const string WriteDateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffzzz";

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, DateTimeOffset value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteRawValue(value.ToString(WriteDateTimeFormat));
    }

    public override DateTimeOffset ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, DateTimeOffset existingValue, bool hasExistingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        DateTimeOffset parsedDate;
        bool hasParsed = DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(reader.Value.ToString(), ReadDateTimeFormat,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
            out parsedDate);
        return hasParsed ?
                parsedDate :
                new DateTimeOffset(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero);
    }
}

Local and Azure locales are Northern Europe.
Worked Around
I was originally getting the framework to de-serialize my data upon trigger:
public async Task<DataPoint> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] Data data,
    ILogger log)

Instead I removed all of the injection of DateTimeOffsetConverter from startup, reverted to triggering with HttpRequestMessage and manually did the de-serialization within the function body.
public async Task<DataPoint> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req,
    ILogger log)
...
data = await JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WordCountData>(await req.ContentReadAsStringAsync());

I can only assume that the framework was unable to do the initial binding.

Please share a [mcve]. Including the object being deserialised to, and DateTimeOffsetFormatConverter.

Locally everything works but deployed in Azure I keep getting: What locale / region are you running locally? On Azure? On local what does DateTime.Now.ToString() result in? What about on your Azure box?

Have added as much non-sensitive info as possible. In local debug the JsonConverter doesn't even seem to be called.

What is the namespace of the JsonConverter you are inheriting from? What json converter are you using (default or Newtonsoft)? Are you calling AddNewtonsoftJson anywhere?

Try this in Function.cs, it worked for me using string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

I have also used Writevalue instaed of WriteRawValue  and in Portal, I have got desired output https://i.imgur.com/YNk9bff.png

.NET 6 reaches End Of Line in less than 2 weeks. Assuming there was such a serious bug in Azure Functions over .NET 6, there's no guarantee it will be in .NET 8, the current LTS version. Switch to .NET 8 first and then try to fix the problem, if it remains. You'll have to switch very soon anyway, and any "fixes" like this will make things harder

Are u still looking without manual deserilaization?

It worked for me using below code :
Function1.cs:
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace RithFunctionApp
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger ri_lg)
        {
            ri_lg.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik, function started");
            string rith = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            var ri_out = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(rith);
            Console.WriteLine($"CreatedDate is: {ri_out.CreatedDate},and DueDate is: {ri_out.DueDate}");
            var cho = ri_out.CreatedDate;
            return new OkObjectResult(cho);
        }
    }
}

And the startup and DateTimeOffsetConverter class is same as yours.
Local:


Portal:


Yes, this is what I changed my code to in order to workaround. The DateTimeOffsetConverter is not even used I don't think and my workaround doesn't use it either. Very strange bug.

Yes, this way it works
